# Cucumber + Spork = undefined method `visit' for #<Object:0x82fcc588> (NoMethodError)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bdd, capybara, spork

I'm tearing my hair out here.  When running Cucumber in Spork-compatible mode (--drb) the **visit()** method doesn't work.

Simply trying the feature step:

```
When I go to the home page
```

calls web step:

```
When /^(?:|I )go to (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  visit path_to(page_name)
end
```

Running "cucumber" on the command line produces the following error:

```
% cucumber
Using the default profile...
Disabling profiles...
.F--

(::) failed steps (::)

undefined method `visit' for #<Object:0x82fcc588> (NoMethodError)
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:24:in `/^(?:|I )go to (.+)$/'
features/authenticated/home_page_visit.feature:10:in `When I go to the home page'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/authenticated/home_page_visit.feature:7 # Scenario: Visit the home page
```

*Does anyone have an idea why visit() would not be available?*

---

**My environment:**

I'm using Rails 2.3.9 and just installed cucumber-rails (0.3.2), cucumber (0.9.2), capybara (0.3.9), and spork (0.8.4).  What's interesting is if I don't use Spork then this works absolutely fine:

```
% cucumber
Using the default profile...
...

1 scenario (1 passed)
3 steps (3 passed)
0m0.114s
```

**Another intersting data point:**

I did a little debugging and deep within the Cucumber gem itself (inside cucumber-0.9.2/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb) I put in a **puts()** to dump out what **self.class.name** was to *stdout*, and when I ran with Spork it spit out "Object" but when I ran it without Spork it printed "Cucumber::Rails::World".

Comment: I recently upgraded to cucumber 0.9, started receiving errors like yours and switched back to cucumber 0.8.5

Comment: Hm. I'll try downgrading. Thx.

Comment: A comment on [cucumber-rails issue #68](http://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber-rails/issues#issue/68) gives a code fix for cucumber, but it has not yet been integrated into cucumber’s master branch. Look for a future release of cucumber to fix it (0.9.3?).

Answer (score 0):

I was the one who opened [this issue](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/issues/68) on github, and I can confirm that it works for cucumber 0.9.3 and beyond.